# PHP: Translation table to convert mutiple values to another value?

Tags: php

I have a a number of values/`IDs` that need to be translated to a single `ID`, what is the recommended method using PHP?

For example, I want `IDs` *38332, 84371, 37939, 1275* to all translate to `ID` *1234* and `IDs`*222, 47391, 798* to all translate to `ID` *1235*, etc. .

I'm thinking PHP has something built-in to handle this efficiently?

Comment: I'd just use an associative array. How many values do you have?

Comment: In which format do you have these number of values/IDs that need to be translated to a single ID?

Comment: about 80 values translating in to 7 others.   I guess that make since in that I can use `$value[38332]=1234;` and the lookup of `$id=$value[$var]` would work (And it's not going to create 38332 empty array elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm thinking PHP has something built-in to handle this efficiently?

You can use the standard array as a map, quickly translating one ID to another:

```php
$table[38332]; # int(1234)
```

depending on how you store your overall translation table, you can create a function that returns the translation from its input:

```php
$table = $translation('I want IDs 38332, 84371, 37939, 1275 to all translate to ID 1234');
$result = $table[1275] ?? null; # int(1234)
```

Example:

```php
$parseId = static fn(string $i) => (int)trim($i);
$translation = static fn(string $buffer): array
    => preg_match_all('~((?:\d+,\s*)+\d+)\s+to all translate to ID\s*(\d+)~', $buffer, $_, PREG_SET_ORDER)
    ? array_reduce($_, static fn (array $carry, array $item): array => [
        $ids = array_map($parseId, explode(',', $item[1])),
        $carry += array_fill_keys($ids, $parseId($item[2])),
        $carry,][2], []) : [];
```

Comment: Thanks, I used your answer in the simple form:  `$prodtable=array(1234=>1234, 38332=>1234, etc..); $commonprodid=$prodtable[$prodid]; ` and it works (and presume there aren't 38333 elements in the array but only allocates what is needed).  The example you provided was a bit confusing for the simple thing I needed but the top section is was the tip I was looking for.

Comment: @user3161924: The function is just exemplary, it returns just a map by parsing the description in the question. It certainly is not a real-life case, more like having the array as you do. Just ignore it then. And 80 ids in the map sounds like a no-brainer, should not do any troubles with the map-array (not at all).

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to accomplish with PHP, here's one way you could do it:

Using this method, you populate the `$map` array, using the id you want to replace with as the key, and the value being an array of the keys you want to be replaced. It then calculates a simple key => value array based on this to make comparison a lot quicker.

Instead of creating a copy of the data, you could use `foreach ($data as &$record)`

```
$data = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'foreign_id' => 38332,
        'text' => 'a'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'foreign_id' => 84371,
        'text' => 'b'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 3,
        'foreign_id' => 37939,
        'text' => 'c'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 4,
        'foreign_id' => 1275,
        'text' => 'd'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'foreign_id' => 222,
        'text' => 'e'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'foreign_id' => 47391,
        'text' => 'f'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 5,
        'foreign_id' => 798,
        'text' => 'g'
    ]
];

$map = [
    123 => [
        38332,
        84371,
        37939,
        1275
    ],
    1235 => [
        222,
        47391,
        798
    ]
];

// Calculate a map to speed things up later
$map_calc = [];
foreach ($map as $destination_id => $ids) {
    foreach ($ids as $id) {
        $map_calc[$id] = $destination_id;
    }
}

$new_data = [];
foreach ($data as $record) {
    if (isset($map_calc[$record['foreign_id']]))
        $record['foreign_id'] = $map_calc[$record['foreign_id']];

    $new_data[] = $record;
}

var_dump($new_data);
```